# Can't seem to understand the error with plugnpay-php

Tags: php, authorization, credit-card

I have been going nuts on working with [plugnpay-php](http://code.google.com/p/plugnpay-php/) library.

After reading the documentation and testing the example code, I still can't seem to make it work.

Here is my index.php

```
require_once './PnP.php';

echo 'starting...';

$p = new PnP( array( 'orderID' => '12345' ));
// $p = new PnP();

$response = $p ->auth(array(
    'card_number' => '4111111111111111',
    'card-name' => 'cardtest',
    'card-amount' => '0.02',
    'card-exp' => '07/15',
    'email' => '',
    'ship-name' => 'cardtest',
    'address1' => '123 West Main Street',
    'address2' => '123 n Street',
    'city' => 'Omaha',
    'state' => 'VT',
    'zip' => '40123',
    'cc-cvv' => '123'
));

echo 'orderID was:: ' . $p->orderID . '<br />';

echo ' Response was <pre> ';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';

echo 'Trans details were: <pre>';
print_r($p -> query_trans());
echo '</pre>';
```

I have tried to run this in debug mode, and everything seems to works fine up to 
[line 395](http://code.google.com/p/plugnpay-php/source/browse/trunk/PnP.php?spec=svn17&r=17#395) in PnP.php and after that noting seems to happen.

Could anyone please tell me, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have `cURL` enabled? Like `var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'))`.

Comment: @CodeAngry
Thanks a lot.
After installing cRUL, it worked like a charm.